# IDE fatal error occurred String index out of range android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

i had this problem with Android Studio 3.2.1 .. Ubuntu OS
every time i start it .. and after gradle build .. comes a notification of IDE error occurred and in details many varies things .. 
then auto complete at XML files don't work .. also preview of it

i added screen shots to last one happened 
i need help and help is appreciated 
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSexz.png)
[the error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPLb7.png)

Comment: It's a bug in Android Studio. I don't think we can do anything about it(?) But you should of course click that `[Report to Google]` button, so they can have a look at it.

Comment: i did so many times .. and added my email in comment and asked for help ..
but nothing happened

any way .. thanks :)